# jquery datatable SearchPanes pagination state not maintains

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I applied a jquery data table with a search panes option and I am enabled state saving in data tables.
it maintains search, sorting, and page length states even after page refreshed, but it is not maintaining pagination state number.

For example,
I have create below example

http://live.datatables.net/vebogala/1/edit

when I navigate to page 2 and refresh the page it does not maintains the state.
could anyone please provide me on how to maintain page numbers state also

Comment: When I search "datatables state" then first hit in google is **https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html**

Comment: Hi davidkonard,
only savestate working properly. but data tables search panes along with savestate property not maintain pagination